# Importing CSV file as a table in Latex but file too long

Tags: tables, import, csv, csvsimple

I am trying to import a CSV file but the data in the table is too long it goes down till the end of the page and disappears without continuing on the next page.

Here's the file:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{mode1_with.csv}
Stimulus,Percentage of 'Alpha'
1,95.8
2,90.6
3,98.8
4,97
5,76.4
6,74.8
7,84.8
8,81.8
9,53.6
10,58.4
11,70.8
12,66.8
13,46.6
14,42.8
15,54
16,52
17,34
18,29.2
19,77.8
20,78.8
21,59.8
22,56.4
23,66.2
24,63.8
25,41.6
26,42.8
27,63.6
28,63.4
29,44
30,40.2
31,49.8
32,48.6
33,80.8
34,80.4
35,90.8
36,89
37,66.4
38,61
39,69.4
40,72.4
41,30.8
42,32.4
43,39.4
44,37
45,18.2
46,20.8
47,13.4
48,30.6
49,83
50,78.4
51,87
52,81.4
53,60.2
54,55.2
55,70.8
56,86.4
57,42.8
58,39.6
59,49.6
60,46.8
61,27
62,27.6
63,78
64,89.4
\end{filecontents*}
```

and this is the code I tried so far:

```
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\begin{document}
\csvreader[tabular=lrrrr,
    table head=\toprule\bfseries Item
             &\bfseries Alpha category (\%) \\\midrule,
    late after line=\\,late after last line=\\\bottomrule,
    before reading={\catcode`\#=12},after reading={\catcode`\#=6}]%
{mode1_with.csv}{1=\Item,2=\Percentage}%
{\Item & \Percentage}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You want to use `longtable`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{csvsimple,longtable,booktabs}
\begin{document}

\csvreader[
  longtable=lrrrr,
  table head=\toprule\bfseries Item &\bfseries Alpha category (\%) \\\midrule,
  late after line=\\,
  late after last line=\\\bottomrule,
  before reading={\catcode`\#=12},after reading={\catcode`\#=6}
]{mode1_with.csv}{1=\Item,2=\Percentage}{\Item & \Percentage} 

\end{document}
```

If you want the header and the bottom rule to be repeated in each page, use

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{csvsimple,longtable,booktabs}
\begin{document}

\csvreader[
  longtable=lrrrr,
  table head=
    \toprule\bfseries Item &\bfseries Alpha category (\%) \\ \midrule\endhead
    \bottomrule\endfoot,
  late after line=\\,
  before reading={\catcode`\#=12},after reading={\catcode`\#=6}
]{mode1_with.csv}{1=\Item,2=\Percentage}{\Item & \Percentage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: In your setup, the header row seems to be missing on the second page.

Comment: @Mico It's easy to do it without using `\csvreader` inside a table.

Answer (score 8):

You need to use a `longtable` rather than a `tabular` environment. If you use `longtable`'s native syntax, it's straightforward to retain full control over objects such as header and footer material on every page.

Naturally, as @egreg's parallel answer shows, it's possible to do so using `csvreader`'s syntax as well.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,csvsimple,longtable}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{lr} 
\toprule
\bfseries Item & \bfseries Alpha category (\%) \\
\midrule \endhead
\bottomrule \endfoot
\csvreader[
    late after line=\\,
    late after last line=,
    before reading={\catcode`\#=12},
    after reading={\catcode`\#=6}]%
    {mode1_with.csv}{1=\Item,2=\Percentage}{\Item & \Percentage}
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```